# Access property using its name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reflection

For example:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim car as new MyCar
  car.chassis.wheel.radius = 15
  Console.WriteLine(car.chassis.wheel.radius)    
End Sub
```

So question is. Is it possible to access the property using its string name like 
Something("car.chassis.wheel.radius") = 15?

Comment: Why would you want to specify its name as a string literal?

Comment: I have to update object's properties' values from many controls, and it is much easier to do it dynamically than directly assign values for each property.

Answer (score 18):

You can, but not as concise as in your question.

This function will get any property of any object by name.

```
Public Function GetPropertyValue(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal PropName As String) As Object
    Dim objType As Type = obj.GetType()
    Dim pInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = objType.GetProperty(PropName)
    Dim PropValue As Object = pInfo.GetValue(obj, Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Return PropValue
End Function
```

I leave error handling to you. And any consequences :)

Comment: The "And any consequences" seems very appropriate here, since I want to do this, but it seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can very easily:

```
Dim radius As Integer = CallByName(car.chassis.wheel, "radius", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallType.Get, Nothing)
```

See [this Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22x2chfx.aspx#Anchor_0) page for reference.

Comment: This helped me. But remember it has a severe effect on performance when you use this on a loop.