# VB.Net :: Send reference for which Property or Method to Sub/Func?

Tags: vb.net, function, methods, properties, subroutine

I want to make a more universal "Progress Bar" which my API has some pre-defined methods. As the progress bar moves, I can update the Message which it displays. I have created a universal "For Each" sub-routine that I can send a Sub, and now I am linking the Progress Bar inside it that also contains a "Cancel" button which I can use to interrupt any loop. But in order to update the message, I want more feedback than just "Item [7/42]", I would rather be able to define "Object.Name" and other times it would need "Object.DisplayName" as each Object I send it will have a different Property that I want to show in the Message.

Is there a way to send an Identifier for which .Property or .Method to reference?

```
Sub FE(Of T)(c As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T), body As Action(Of T), Optional pb As ProgBar = Nothing, Optional _id As Identifier = Nothing)
    If pb IsNot Nothing Then pb.Start(c.Count)
    For Each i As T In c
        If pb IsNot Nothing AndAlso pb.Cancel Then Exit For
        body(i)
        If pb IsNot Nothing Then pb.Update(i._id)
    Next
    If pb IsNot Nothing Then pb.Close
End Sub
```

The final input to the function is where I want help, I don't know how to describe what it could be?

```
Optional _id As Identifier = Nothing
```

So I could invoke this

```
FE(Of Sketch)(collection(Of Sketch), _
    Sub(x As Sketch)
        x.Visible = Not x.Visible
    End Sub, _
    New ProgBar("Some Title"), _
    .Name )
```

Then it could use the .Name when it updates the ProgBar as the Message String. Obviously some error checking would have to be programmed, but I think this gets the point across?

Comment: You can pass the object of your choice, and use a `Select-Case` inside your method to tell which object it is, and then choose the property appropriate to the object. This would work if you have a limited number of objects, and all objects of the same type use the same property the same way inside the method.

Comment: You could create an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/) that all the objects you send would implement.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/) that all the objects you send would implement:

```
Interface IProgressBarItem
    Property DisplayText As String
End Interface
```

Your `Sketch` class would then implement this interface:

```
Public Class Sketch
    Implements IProgressBarItem

    Public Property Name As String Implements IProgressBarItem.DisplayText

End Class

Public Class OtherObject
    Implements IProgressBarItem

    Public Property DisplayName As String Implements IProgressBarItem.DisplayText

End Class
```

In your main loop, you can cast you `i` object to `IProgressBarItem` and use  `DisplayText`:

```
If pb IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim pbi As IProgressBarItem = CType(i, IProgressBarItem)
    pb.Update(pbi.DisplayText)
End If
```

This offsets the decision-making of what property to display to the object itself.

You should add code to verify that `i` implements `IProgressBarItem` though.

Another approach is to use Reflection as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942699/access-property-using-its-name-in-vb-net). You would just pass the property name as a String parameter to `FE` (instead of `_id`) and use [GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-7.0) to get the property value ([Miroslav Zadravec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8239/miroslav-zadravec) code here):

```
Public Function GetPropertyValue(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal PropName As String) As Object
    Dim objType As Type = obj.GetType()
    Dim pInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = objType.GetProperty(PropName)
    Dim PropValue As Object = pInfo.GetValue(obj, Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Return PropValue
End Function
```

Comment: Your link to Miroslav Zadravec's response led me to another:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname?view=net-7.0

`Interaction.CallByName`

Which is a Microsoft.VisualBasic option that seems to work. For some reason, his code produces "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." During the "GetValue" operation.

I will look further in to Interfaces as well, as I like that option.

Comment: @deDevo Interfaces are probably the cleanest way if you are using your own objects. If not, Reflection is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection was the solution:

```
Dim m As String = pbMsg
Dim n As Func(Of Object, String(), String) = _
    Function(j As Object, k As String())
        If k(0) = "" Then k = k.Skip(1).ToArray
        If k.Length > 1 Then
            Return n(Interaction.CallByName(j, k(0), CallType.Get), k.Skip(1).ToArray)
        Else
            Return Interaction.CallByName(j, k(0), CallType.Get)
        End If
    End Function

If pb IsNot Nothing AndAlso pb.Cancel Then cancel = True : Exit For
If pb IsNot Nothing Then
    If m.Contains(".") Then m = n(i, m.Split("."))
    pb.Update(m)
End If
```